# How to slice multiple fasta sequences to substrings with the length in a range in fasta format?

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

Given a file containing multiple protein sequences in fasta format with different lengthes, how to generate a fasta format protein fragments (substrings) with length i ( i is greater or equal to 5 but not more than the length of each protein,respectively) ?

For example,the protein sequences file:

```
>NP_12345.1
ACDEFGH
>XP_543211.2
KLMNOP
...
```

I want the output fasta format:

```
>NP_12345.1(1-5)
ACDEF
>NP_12345.1(1-6)
ACDEFG
>NP_12345.1(1-7)
ACDEFGH
>NP_12345.1(2-6)
CDEFG
>NP_12345.1(2-7)
CDEFGH
>NP_12345.1(3-7)    
DEFGH
>XP_543211.2(1-5)
KLMNO
>XP_543211.2(1-6)
KLMNOP
>XP_543211.2(2-6)
LMNOP
...
```

Could anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Note:
I can use

```
Seqkit sliding -s 1 -W 5
```

to generate the fasta format of protein fragments or peptides with only 5 amino acids, but if peptides of 6 amino acids, I must modify the parameter -W 6. Any other one-stop solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl, please try:

```
perl -e '
$/ = "\xd\xa";  # required if input.txt is created with DOS newline format
while (<>) {
    chomp($name = $_);
    chomp($seq = <>);
    $len = length($seq);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $len - 5; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 5; $j <= $len; $j++) {
            printf("%s(%d-%d)\n", $name, $i+1, $j);
            print substr($seq, $i, $j-$i), "\n";
        }
    }
}' input.txt
```

which yields:

```
>NP_12345.1(1-5)
ACDEF
>NP_12345.1(1-6)
ACDEFG
>NP_12345.1(1-7)
ACDEFGH
>NP_12345.1(2-6)
CDEFG
>NP_12345.1(2-7)
CDEFGH
>NP_12345.1(3-7)
DEFGH
>XP_543211.2(1-5)
KLMNO
>XP_543211.2(1-6)
KLMNOP
>XP_543211.2(2-6)
LMNOP
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much! I run your code "perl -e 'while (<>) {chomp($name = $_);chomp($seq = <>);$len = length($seq);for ($i = 0; $i <= $len - 5; $i++) {for ($j = $i + 5; $j <= $len; $j++) {printf("%s(%d-%d)\n", $name, $i+1, $j);print substr($seq, $i, $j-$i), "\n";}}}' input.txt", it is fast and give me result: (1-5)2345.1
ACDEF
(1-6)2345.1
ACDEFG
(1-7)2345.1
ACDEFGH
(1-8)2345.1
ACDEFGH
(2-6)2345.1
CDEFG
(2-7)2345.1
CDEFGH
(2-8)2345.1
CDEFGH
(3-7)2345.1
DEFGH
(3-8)2345.1
DEFGH
(4-8)2345.1
EFGH
(1-5)43211.2
KLMNO
(1-6)43211.2
KLMNOP
(2-6)43211.2
LMNOP

Comment: Obviously, (3-7)2345.1
DEFGH
(3-8)2345.1
DEFGH

Comment: are duplicated, and (4-8)2345.1
EFGH is not the result that I wanted. Another point is that the data structre of the result is different from what I wanted, which is, for example, >NP_12345.1(1-5)
ACDEF. Is there any bugs or other problems? Thanks a lot! @tshiono

Comment: It seems your `input.txt` is created with DOS newline format, that is, it contains `\r` and `\n` at the end of lines. I've modified my answer to accept the format. Would you test it again? BR.

Comment: yeah, you are right, it now works perfectly ! You are really genius !!! Thank you for your great help.